# VPython: Iterating a function to create a new curve every run

Tags: python, vpython

I'm creating a program to find the optimum angle to launch a projectile at a given speed, in order to hit a target a given distance away.

i have this code:

```
def Trajectory(angle):
    position = vector(0,0,0)
    poscurve.plot(pos=position)
    velocity = v0 * vector(cos(angle*pi/180), sin(angle*pi/180), 0)
    while (position.y > 0) or (velocity.y > 0):
        dx = velocity * dt  # update dx and dv
        dv = g * dt

        position = position + dx # apply the updates to velocity and position
        velocity = velocity + dv

        poscurve.plot(pos=position)
   return position
```

The problem is, this program repeats this function multiple times, with different angles. When it repeats it, it connects the first point of the new curve to the last point of the previous curve, because the function uses the same `poscurve.plot(pos=position)` every time. How do I make the function generate a new curve each time it iterates this function?

(there are variables defined outside of this code snippet, the program conceptually works fine, just how the graph looks)

Comment: It is not immediately clear where `poscurve` is coming from. From what I can see, it just adds a new point to a dataset (that is later plotted). To create each time a new curve, you either create a new `poscurve` object, or maintain a list of `poscurve`'s, or even add a new curve/line to the existing graph/scene

Comment: @Oerd sorry, `poscurve` is defined as `poscurve = gcurve(gdisplay = win, color=color.blue)` and the problem is I don't know how to make a new `gcurve` each time, is it even possible to run the same function over and over and have it use a different variable for the trajectory each time?

Answer (score 0):

Add `poscurve` as a parameter:

```
def Trajectory(angle,poscurve):
    position = vector(0,0,0)
    poscurve.plot(pos=position)
    velocity = v0 * vector(cos(angle*pi/180), sin(angle*pi/180), 0)
    while (position.y > 0) or (velocity.y > 0):
        dx = velocity * dt  # update dx and dv
        dv = g * dt

        position = position + dx # apply the updates to velocity and position
        velocity = velocity + dv

        poscurve.plot(pos=position)
   return position
```

Then, pass in a new `poscurve` every time. You can just call `gcurve` again to create a new object.